# Which mongodb operator is opposite to $ (projection) for retrieving any element matching the query

Tags: mongodb

How to get all embedded documents that match query? As documentation says:

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an array from the
>   query results **to contain only the first element** matching the query
>   document.

Example:

```
{ "_id" : 7, semester: 3, "grades" : [ { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
                                   { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
                                   { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 } ] }

{ "_id" : 8, semester: 3, "grades" : [ { grade: 92, mean: 88, std: 8 },
                                   { grade: 78, mean: 90, std: 5 },
                                   { grade: 88, mean: 85, std: 3 } ] }
```

For example, I need grades that `std < 8`, operator $ returns only the first matching result, so we have two objects:

```
{ grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 }
{ grade: 78, mean: 90, std: 5 }
```

but result that I need:

```
{ grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
{ grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 }

{ grade: 78, mean: 90, std: 5 },
{ grade: 88, mean: 85, std: 3 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework for this.

```
.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$grades"},
    {$match: {"grades.std": {$lt: 8}}
])
```

[Documentation on aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)